# jqvmap change hoverColor by onLabelShow

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqvmap

i'm using the plugin jqvmap ( http://www.jqvmap.com/ ) and initialized an map:

```
var setMap = function (name) {
    var data = {
        map: 'world_en',
        hoverColor: null,
        hoverOpacity: null,
        values: {
            "us": 11,
            "ca": 33,
            "ru": 22,
            ...
        },
        ...
        showTooltip: true,
        onRegionOver: function (event, code, region) {

            //Here is my problem
            if (code == 'ca' || code == 'us' || ...) data.hoverColor = '#c9dfaf';
        },
        onRegionOut: function (event, code, region) {
            data.hoverColor = null;
        },
    };

    data.map = name + '_en';
    var map = jQuery('#vmap_' + name);
    if (!map) {
        return;
    }
    map.width(map.parent().parent().width());
    map.show();
    map.vectorMap(data);
    map.hide();
}

setMap("world");
```

Now i tried to change the hoverColor, in the function *onRegionOver*, because i want only hovercolor for the states, which have data, but it did not change anything? The hoverColor is still null. Can you help me, whats wrong with this?

Comment: Did you get it working with the solution below?

Answer (score 1):

I tried it on a map, and found this solution:

if (code == 'ca' || code == 'ca') jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap('set', 'colors', {us: '#c9dfaf', ca: #c9dfaf});

I have got it working on my map which is in a div with ID vmap, as you can see.